# Match font between \texttt and text inside lstlisting

Tags: fonts, listings

I am trying to match the font between the line that says:
 reg [8:0] data_saved [0:3]; // memory declaration

and the rest of the lines that are inside lstlisting.
Here is what I get:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass [11pt] {article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{listings}
\input std-defs
\input EECE2323-header
\begin{document}
\noindent
\lab{3}{LAB3 - Arithmetic and Logic Unit Part II and Register File}

    \texttt{reg [8:0] data\_saved [0:3]; // memory declaration }

and then initialize its values with the \texttt{initial} declaration:


\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin=10em]
// Initialize Inputs Stimulus
initial
  begin
     data_saved[0] = 9'b000000001;
     data_saved[1] = 9'b000000010;
     data_saved[2] = 9'b000000011;
     data_saved[3] = 9'b000000100;
     end
\end{lstlisting}


\textbf{Use alu\_reg\_file\_tb.v as your Testbench template.}

\end{document}
```

But if I try to add `\texttt` to the lstlisting than I just see the word `\texttt` in the text.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Add the options `basicstyle=\ttfamily` and `columns=fullflexible` to `\lstset`.

Comment: @egreg, I added the options you mentioned and I see no change in the pdf..

Comment: @Tlalit In that case please incorporate it into the example, so that we see what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have a `\lstset` instruction in your preamble:

```
\documentclass [11pt] {article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{listings}
%\input std-defs
%\input EECE2323-header

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
}

\begin{document}

%\noindent
%\lab{3}{LAB3 - Arithmetic and Logic Unit Part II and Register File}

    \texttt{reg [8:0] data\_saved [0:3]; // memory declaration }

and then initialize its values with the \texttt{initial} declaration:


\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin=10em]
// Initialize Inputs Stimulus
initial
  begin
     data_saved[0] = 9'b000000001;
     data_saved[1] = 9'b000000010;
     data_saved[2] = 9'b000000011;
     data_saved[3] = 9'b000000100;
     end
\end{lstlisting}


\textbf{Use alu\_reg\_file\_tb.v as your Testbench template.}

\end{document}
```

I have commented out the parts that I can't use (the two `\input` instructions and the line with the `\lab` macro), but for the rest I didn't touch the file, apart from changing the call to `epsfig` into the call to `graphicx`. The former package is obsolete and should not be used in new documents.

[image]